# No. Of ways of folding a paper strip

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

You have given a strip which is divided into n+1 identical parts by n folds on the strip. Now find the no. Of ways in which you can fold the whole strip into a single identical part..!

Comment: This was a problem in Martin Gardner's column in Scientific America decades ago.

Comment: Here is a discussion of [folding](https://www.robertdickau.com/stampfolding.html) a strip of stamps.

Comment: But he doesn't provide answer to my question about

Comment: See [OEIS A000136](http://oeis.org/A000136)

Comment: But he does make the claim "There seems not to be a closed-form formula to compute the counts of labeled stamp foldings, though many have tried."

Answer (score 1):

With the restriction imposed by $n$ folds producing $n+1$ identical parts (folding the strip in half and in half again results in $4$ identical parts but there are actually $3$ folds in the strip's single thickness), then the number of ways to fold the strip into identical parts is $2^n$. Conceptually, each fold can go in one of two directions so the $2$ possibilities of the first fold is followed by $2$ possibilities for the next fold etc. Each resulting configuration of folds has a similar configuration with surface A flipped with surface B. There are practical limitations of actually doing this for some folding configurations as n gets large.

Comment: But for $n=3$ you can have mountain folds between $1$ and $2$ and between $2$ and $3$, then a valley fold between $3$ and $4$.  The squares can then be stacked  $2134$ or $2341$  I believe these should be counted as distinct.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I see what you are saying, for identical folds the strip can be stacked in different ways. The way I interpreted the question was simply a fold configuration. For n=3, this would result in 12 configurations. I'll look to see if there is a pattern for increasing n. Thanks